# NODE create json file and export to ftp server location

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ftp

I am using an async fetch with an api to get some json information. I am filtering it down and then I need to save the info into a new json file and upload to an FTP server. Getting the info and setting up all the information is fine, I am looking for suggestions about the uploading new file to ftp.

Thank you in advance for the help!!!!

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request with json file to request FTP server